# Finding BFS Parent-Relation Array

Tags: parent-child, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I'm a student, currently covering DFS and BFS for graphs. While doing a online lab for the course, I came across the question

"After completion of BFS starting from vertex 5, the parent relation (array) is [ _  ,  _  ,  _  ,  _  ,  _  ,  _  ]"

The graph in question being written as:

U 6
0 4
5 4
4 2
2 3
3 0
3 4

The answer given (which I eventually found through guess-and-check), was: 
[4, None, 4, 4, 5, None]

I may be misunderstanding some fundamentals of graph traversals, but after spending over half an hour searching, I still cannot find a reason for this answer, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question as posted is not clear to me. The graph representation is not clear (what does each pair of numbers represent  ? what does U represent ? What does "parent array" mean ?

Comment: In terms of the question, that is exactly how it was written in the lab. I'll try to clarify though, now that I understand slightly better.

Comment: The "parent array" is an array which, as explained in the answer below, states the parent vertex for each vertex, with each item in the array representing each of the vertices, in order.
The U states that the graph is Undirected, so the links between the vertices have no direction, as opposed to those of a Directed graph.
The pairs of numbers are the links between the vertices. For example, vertices 0 and 4 are linked, as are 5 and 4, in the pairs that are shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each gap in the parent array represents each vertex. In the example above, when the source vertex is 5, the parent vertex for vertices 0,2,3 is vertex 4, so the points 0, 2 and 3 in the parent array have the value 4 designated to them. Similarly, vertex 4 has 5 as a parent, so the array follows suit. Finally, vertices 1 and 5 have no parent, 1 because it is disconnected from the graph, and 5 because it is the source in this case. Therefore these vertices are marked in the array as "None".
Hope this helps anybody who encounters the same issue.